# Is there a better way to combine multiple scripts for Word in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cpu-word

I have been trying to run a batch file, that reads through a text file, and runs a bunch of powershell script files. However, nothing seems to happen when I try it this way.

I have been using this as my batch.ps1 file:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

if(!$word){
    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word.Visible = $false
}

$directory = "C:\temp"
$DocxFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter "*.docm"
$counter = 1

#Menu
Write-Host "==========" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
Write-Host "===MENU===" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
Write-Host "==========" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

$(for($i=0; $i -lt $DocxFiles.Count; $i++){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'File Name'       = "${i}: $($DocxFiles.BaseName[$i])"
        'Last Write Time' = $DocxFiles.LastWriteTime[$i]
            }
        }) | Out-Host
Write-Host ""

$fileToEdit = Read-Host -Prompt "Select a file from the menu"
Clear-Host

$fileToEdit = "$($DocxFiles[$fileToEdit].FullName)"




# Get list of scripts to run
$file = Get-Content "C:\paths_02.txt"

# Loop through each script and run it, passing the file to edit as a parameter
foreach ($line in $file) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("#")) {continue}
    $scriptPath = $line.Trim()
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File $scriptPath -fileToEdit $fileToEdit" -Wait

    
}

$word.Quit()
    
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

and then this is an example of a script that should be being read:

```
param($fileToEdit)


$input = $fileToEdit

$doc = $word.Documents.Open($input,$false,$false,$false)
$header = $doc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range
#delete header
$header.Delete()
#select footer
$footer = $doc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).Range
#Delete footer
$footer.Delete()
$doc.Save()
$doc.Close()
Write-Host "The header and footer of the file '$input' have been deleted" -ForegroundColor Green
```

But, like I said, nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by nothing is happening? It should at least be asking for input from `Read-Host`

One problem I see is that you are starting separate powershell instances for each script, and they won't have the `$word` COM stuff loaded. This also means you won't see any errors they throw.

Try and just [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.3#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) each script instead like:

```bash
# uncommented script names
$scripts = (Get-Content "C:\test\test.txt") -notmatch '^#'

foreach ($line in $scripts) {
  Write-Output "running script $line"

  # execute each script
  if (Test-Path $line) {
    . $line.Trim() -fileToEdit $fileToEdit
  }
  else { Write-Error "could not find $line" }
}
```

---

For readability, I don't recommend loading your sub-scripts as text paths from another file. Powershell supports lots of ways of bundling up multiple scripts like loading them as [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.3#parameters-in-scripts) you can run directly